# Mean of this density function is giving me trouble

Tags: probability-theory

I know how to calculate the mean of a density function. This particular density function is $f(x)=2x^{-3}$ for $x>1$.

I get as a result $-2$. I am not very good at math... and I tend to make silly mistakes.

Intuitively positive $2$ makes sense since the function only takes positive values. However when you do an integral of the function from 1 to infinity, arent you supposed to substract the lower end of the integral (one) to the upper part (infinity)? If so, you would be subtracting $2$ from the upper end (0).

Any ideas as to why I should just change the sign to make it positive?

Comment: You're forgetting the factor of $(-1)$, as $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{x} = -\frac{1}{x^2}$.

Comment: For the mean, we want to integrate $2x^{-2}$. An antiderivative is $-2x^{-1}$. "Plug in." We get $0-(-2)$.

Comment: Oh yes, Oh Im so silly! I forgot that step> I need to get some sleep!